# How to call python module from visual foxpro

Tags: python

I had created a linear regression module in python.  This python module, i want to call from visual foxpro to show the result.  Can any one tell me how to do it?

Comment: Please show what your code

Comment: Using python37.dll, i am trying to call my python module.  Using declare method i instantiate the dll methods and  trying to execute py_initialize() method, system closing the visual foxpro application.

Comment: Any progress on this? I suddenly have a need to call a python script from FoxPro with a python virtual environment.